# WPF BitmapFrame to BitmapImage

Tags: wpf, bitmap, bitmapimage

I have a BitmapFrame from deserialization. I need to convert this to BitmapImage. How to do that?
I used this code:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/31808363-6b00-43dd-8ea8-0917a35d62ad/how-to-convert-stream-to-bitmapsource-and-how-to-convert-bitmapimage-to-bitmapsource-in-wpf?forum=wpf

The problem is that BitmapImage does not have a Source property, only StreamSource or UriSource.

serialization part:

```
public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
        {
            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
            JpegBitmapEncoder encoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
            encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(image.UriSource));
            encoder.QualityLevel = 30;
            encoder.Save(stream);
            stream.Flush();
            info.AddValue("Image", stream.ToArray());
...
```

deserialization :

```
public ImageInfo(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
        {
            //Deserialization Constructorbyte[] encodedimage = (byte[])info.GetValue("Image", typeof(byte[]));
            if (encodedimage != null)
            {
                MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(encodedimage);
                JpegBitmapDecoder decoder = new JpegBitmapDecoder(stream, BitmapCreateOptions.None, BitmapCacheOption.Default);
                Image = new BitmapImage();
                Image.BeginInit();
                //Image.StreamSource = ...  decoder.Frames[0];
                Image.EndInit();
                Image.Freeze();
            }
...
```

I would need something effective instead of the comment above...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides that you don't really need this conversion (because you can use a BitmapFrame wherever you otherwise use a BitmapImage), you could directly decode a BitmapImage from an encoded bitmap in a byte array.

It is not necessary to explicitly use a BitmapDecoder. When you assign a Stream to the BitmapImage's `StreamSource` property, the frameworks uses the appropriate decoder automatically. You must take care to set `BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad` when the Stream should be closed immediately after the BitmapImage was created.

```
Image = new BitmapImage();
using (var stream = new MemoryStream(encodedimage))
{
    Image.BeginInit();
    Image.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
    Image.StreamSource = stream;
    Image.EndInit();
}
Image.Freeze();
```

Comment: Thanks, it works great! By the way when I serialize images with the above GetObjectData method I get around 300-400KB / image (serialized). All of the images are at most 150 pixel wide (with ratio of 4:3 or 16:9) with qualitylevel=30. I think this is rather big, am I wrong?

Comment: That is way too much for 150x100 or so pixels. It should be a few KB only. Are you sure you're measuring the encoded byte array size? Does it decrease with lower QualityLevel?

Comment: Oooops, I have encoded the UriSource of the image, so the full sized image instead of the 150x... thumbnail. Now it's 5-7KB/image :) Thanks for your help again!